# convert old dart to new dart version

Tags: flutter

I want to correct the error of the code. My Problem is:

details.dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSNtp.png)

Non-nullable instance fields must be initialized.

```
class _DetailState extends State<Detail> {
  final String id, ar_title, en_title;

  _DetailState(this.id, this.ar_title, this.en_title);

//String is problem ??



"Model"

class ItemListModel {
  final List<ItemModel> itemList;

  ItemListModel({required this.itemList});

  factory ItemListModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> json, String groupId) {
    List<ItemModel> list = <ItemModel>[];
    //list = json.map((model) => ItemModel.fromJson(model)).toList();

    json.forEach((element) {
      if (element["group_id"].toString() == groupId) {
        list.add(ItemModel.fromJson(element));
      }
    });

    return new ItemListModel(itemList: list);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a "Non-nullable instance fields must be initialized." error?  The fields you've shown do seem to be properly initialized.  Are you sure that your editor isn't showing you [warnings about not using lowerCamelCase variable names](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/non_constant_identifier_names)?  If you are getting an initialization error, please post an example that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: _DetailState(this.id, this.ar_title, this.en_title); _DetailState (red underline) 

ERROR

Non-nullable instance field 'itemListModel' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.dartnot_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field

Comment: The `itemListModel` member isn't in the code you provided.  The error message tells you what to do.